# Backbone collection.where error

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I assume I am doing something silly and clearly wrong, but I am baffled. Using CoffeeScript and marionette backbone, I want to create a methods on my collection that will set most models to selected and then set all selected to unselected. I assumed

```
deselectAll: ->
  @where({selected: true})
```

would get me the selected models and I could iterate over that (for model in selected) and set the models. But I cannot get @where to work and instead get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.matches is not a function
```

from backbones:

```
where: function(attrs, first) {
  var matches = _.matches(attrs);
  return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
    return matches(model.attributes);
  });
},
```

**UPDATE**

It is currently working with filter:

```
@filter (model) ->
  model.get 'selected'
```

and it seems somewhat more complicated than where was, but perhaps not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backbone <= 1.2.1` is not compatible with `underscore >= 1.8.0`. Upgrade your `backbone` to 1.2.2 or 1.2.3.

In `underscore` 1.8.0 function `matches` is deprecated and renamed to `matcher`. See [underscore changelog](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog)

Comment: Ah! Good find. Thanks a ton. Knew it was something very simple... +1 for the link as soon as my rep is high enough